# WPF - The value specified in System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder caused an exception

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

So Once again i came here to get some anwsers to problems i can't resolve them by myself, so my problem is im getting a xamlparse execption each time the button style is loaded, inside the style i have a < rectangle > that should get one color defined by the user from a query on my MVVM. So far there was no problems, the problem is trying to give that color value to the grandientstop inside the LinearGradientBrush of the rectangle. The xaml code im using:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="{Binding Path=StrColor, Converter={StaticResource FadingBrushConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Rectangle}}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="70" Margin="0,0,0,0" RadiusY="5" RadiusX="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="70">
<Rectangle.Effect>
     <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="8"/>
</Rectangle.Effect>
</Rectangle>
```

The "StrColor" is a Color property.

On my MVVM i have this converter:

```
 Public Class FadingBrushConverter
        Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
        ' TODO: Do some type-checking
        Dim brush = New LinearGradientBrush()
        Dim color = DirectCast(value, Color)
        Dim Bcolor As System.Windows.Media.Color
        Bcolor.R = 0
        Bcolor.G = 0
        Bcolor.B = 0

        brush.StartPoint = New Point(0.5, 0)
        brush.EndPoint = New Point(0.5, 1.27)
        brush.GradientStops.Add(New GradientStop(color, 0))
        brush.GradientStops.Add(New GradientStop(Bcolor, 1))

        Return brush

    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotSupportedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

I really dont know what am i doing wrong here, i have been looking on the internet but so far i had no luck in fixing this problem!

I also have used DynamicResource but with no success!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: please provide more XAML for better understanding of your issue..

Comment: You really dont need any other xmal to understand the problem and anyways i found a work around for it. i Created a readonly property that does the same as the converter, and then i changed the Fill property with Fill="{Binding ReadOnlyProperty}" and now its working as i want to. i really cant see why he was not working with the converter.. anyways i have the problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the binding. "Fill" property of the Rectangle is bound to the strColor property of its parent Rectangle (with the `"RelativeSource FindAncestor"` argument). I don't think it is realistic to assume that a rectangle is placed in another rectangle. Even if is is somehow the case, the built-in Rectangle element doesn't have a `strColor` property. If you want to get the color from the ViewModel, you should try something in the sort of:

```
{Binding Path=StrColor, Converter={StaticResource FadingBrushConverter}"
```

Of course, this is assuming that the DataContext is set correctly.